# How to throw exception

Tags: c#

I am troubling to call catch. I have to call catch when the variable res = -1.

```
try
{
int res = -1;
//Not sure how to call catch or throw expception
}
catch(exception ex)
{
console.writeLine(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/

Comment: Don't throw exceptions to handle code flow.

Comment: Maybe that variable comes as method parameter, then you should thow an `ArgumentException`. If it's the result of your method you should instead return a result indicating that it was invalid, for example an enum(or `bool`) and the result-value as out-parammeter or a `CalculationResult`-instance that has an `IsValid` property. That's much cleaner than throwing an exception up the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to throw an exception when res is `-1`:

```cs
if (res == -1) {
   // but please use a more appropriate Exception class
   throw new Exception("Throwing my exception"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean, you wouldn't "call" the catch, you would reach the catch in the event of an error. but if you were to throw an exception, is this not the syntax you are looking for?

```
try
{
   int res = -1;
   //Not sure how to call catch or throw expception
   if(res == -1)
   {
      throw new Exception("Custom Exception Message");
   }
}
catch(exception ex)
{

console.writeLine(ex.message);
}
```